# Mapping one Entity into two different tables using annotations

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have a lot of trouble with the following problem.
I have an Entity "Home" which I use at two different locations within my code.
The problem is, that it is necessary to map this entity to different tables depending
on the class they were used in.

If we assume I would have the two classes Class1 and Class2. Both classes have the 
an attribute of the "Home" type. Now I want that of attribute within class1 is mapped to the Table "CLASS1_HOME" and the attribute of class2 is mapped to the table "CLASS2_HOME".

I know that this is possible by e.g., using "MappedSuperClass" for the class "Home" and create a further class "Second_Home" which inherits all attributes from class "home". But my Question is if there is a possibilty to this without inheritance, because the attributes of home will not change and I think the "inheritance" solution is a kind of "dirty". Moreover, I want to this only by using annotations.

Is there a way to do it as I described it ?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use inheritance, and if you are saving HOME the same way in both CLASS1_HOME and CLASS2_HOME table, I do suggest something like this:

```
public class Home{
boolean Class1;
}
```

in this case when you persist it you can simply figure out if this is for Class1 or not. And if you want, based on the flag persisted in your database, you can create two views of CLASS1_Home and CLASS2_Home